# Combining multiple time series in tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyquant

What is the tidyverse equivalent of 'merge'?
Trying to do a small project in tidyverse... combining several time series into one by 'date':

```
t3 <- tq_get("DGS3", get = 'economic.data', from='1900-01-01')
t5 <- tq_get("DGS5", get = 'economic.data', from='1900-01-01')
t10 <- tq_get("DGS10", get = 'economic.data', from='1900-01-01')
t30 <- tq_get("DGS30", get = 'economic.data', from='1900-01-01')
```

?? data <- full_join(t3, *** all above, by = "date")

Comment: place it in a `list` and do the `full_join` i.e. `list(t3, t4, t10, t30) %>% reduce(full_join, by = 'date')`

Comment: Thank you!  I could not have figured that out with my current knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to place the objects in a `list` and then `reduce` the datasets to a single data with `full_join`

```
library(tidyverse)
list(t3, t4, t10, t30) %>% 
     reduce(full_join, by = 'date')
```